# Solving regular Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville, hermite-polynomials

I was studying Schrödinger's equation for a school paper and wanted to solve it in a bit broader context than the potential well. I wanted to use a potential function $$V(x,y,z) = \chi(x) + \gamma(y) + \zeta(z)$$ for continuous (maybe continuously differentiable, don't know if that will matter later) functions $\chi(x), \gamma(y)$, and $\zeta(z)$. After using separation of variables, I get this equation (and others analogous for y and z):
$$X''(x) + (\chi(x) + \alpha)X(x) = 0$$
Where alpha is proportional to the separation constant. I was wondering whether there is a way to solve this without directly specifying $\chi(x)$. It wouldn't be a problem to have series and/or integrals.

Should that not be possible (as is my hunch), is there a nice solution if I let $\chi(x)$, $\gamma(y)$, and $\zeta(z)$ be polynomials? I heard this may be possible using something called "Hermite polynomials", which I'm far from familiar with, so would appreciate some help here as well!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually need explicit solutions? This problem is basically asking for the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of an operator with an arbitrary variable coefficient, which is something typically handled numerically or by establishing qualitative results

Comment: No, there is no such way.

Comment: Explicit solutions would be preferable, yes. Nevertheless, my initial hunch was that this wasn't possible. I imagine that, if I were to limit $\chi(x)$ to be a polynomial, I could solve it using Power Series/Frobenius' method given some initial conditions, but was wondering if someone knew of something I could do regardless of the form of $\chi(x)$.